# Adding TextBox and other controls to an HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game using HTML5 canvas,
How do I add a TextBox and buttons to the canvas ?

Thanks,
SW

Comment: are you talking about an input of type text?

Comment: Yes, typed text, with scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look a this post

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

Comment: How do I position the control at a specific location on the my canvas ?

Comment: I think you have to do that using CSS,